# Pushing to heroku gives me Unable to get OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN, using default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my application on heroku server, which was earlier deployed on Open shift. It was working fine before my last push now giving me the following error. Although , It is working fine on my local machine. Error is as below.

```
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-05-05T10:46:19.190707+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2014-05-05T10:46:19.209705+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to get OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN, using default
2014-05-05T10:46:19.209862+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to get OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN, using default
2014-05-05T10:46:19.929309+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930376+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930344+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930368+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930373+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930372+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930377+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930378+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930374+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930348+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930379+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930381+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930391+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930390+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930394+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930395+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930396+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930401+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930402+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930404+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930409+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930406+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930408+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930413+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930411+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930410+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930422+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930425+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930426+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930427+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930428+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930430+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-05-05T10:46:19.930433+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-05-05T10:46:21.257306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-05T10:46:21.258394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

**Update**
My database.yml looks like this

```
sqlite: &sqlite
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%= Rails.env %>.sqlite3

mysql: &mysql
  adapter: mysql2
  database: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']%>"
  username: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']%>"
  password: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']%>"
  host:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']%>
  port:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']%>

postgresql: &postgresql
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']%>
  username: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME']%>
  password: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD']%>
  host:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST']%>
  port:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT']%>
  min_messages: ERROR
  reconnect: false

defaults: &defaults
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  <<: *<%= ENV['RAILS_DB'] || "sqlite" %>

development:
  <<: *defaults

test: &test
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

My config/initializers/secret_token.rb looks like this.

```
require File.join(Rails.root,'lib','openshift_secret_generator.rb')

    RailsApp::Application.config.secret_token = initialize_secret(
      :token,
      'my token'
    )
```

Comment: Can you please share the `config/database.yml` file in the question. Hide the keys/ tokens if any with `xxx`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku will rewrite the `database.yml` for all versions of Rails < 4.1 - so it's safe to assume that's not the problem here.

I would be tempted to look in `config\initializers\secret_token.rb` as the cause of your problem, I suspect that will be accessing `OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN` which is erroring when the application is initialized.

Comment: Please have a look updated the question added content of secret_token.rb file.

Comment: ok, so that's calling the `initialize_secret` function that's probably in the included file `lib\openshift_secret_generator.rb`. I would include just remove the included file reference and have `RailsApp::Application.config.secret_token = "somerandomreallylongtokenhere"` instead.

Comment: When I try to do that I get undefined method `initialize_secret' for main:Object (NoMethodError) in my local version of code.

Comment: is `initialize_secret` used somewhere else in that file? Can you update OP with your new secret_token.rb contents

Comment: Now I have just his line in my secret_token.rb file RailsApp::Application.config.secret_token = 'new token'